# unable to rename linux hostname?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machines

I got one problem with my linux webserver where I deployed from Virtual Machine template, usually i go to the console and then

issue the command **hostname NEWSERVERNAME** to make it happens and then followed by editing the **[image: /etc/hosts]** file and its done, but how come this time after the reboot it reverts back to the old template name ?

so i want it to be "wordpress" as the hostname but instead it reverts back to SSV as the name ?

any suggestion and comments is appreciated here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, I change the hostname using the following commands WITHOUT REBOOT:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/hostname
$ sudo vim /etc/hosts
$ sudo /etc/init.d/hostname restart
```

First, edit both files `/etc/hostname` to change the hostname, and edit `/etc/hosts` to add the new name. Then, run the hostname script as shown above.

All you need to do now is to terminate your current SSH session and reconnect to see the new host name.

Answer (score 2):

Check /etc/hosts, /etc/hostname, and /etc/mailname.  You may want to run `find /etc -type f | xargs grep $(hostname)` to list all references.

Answer (score 2):

In Debian and Ubuntu (which looks like the distribution you're using) to make your hostname stick through reboots, set it by editing the `hostname` file:

```
echo "wordpress" > /etc/hostname
```

Then make sure that your VPS hosting company will not override your hostname configuration via DHCPCD. In `/etc/default/dhcpcdp` ensure that the `SET_HOSTNAME` directive is commented out or it is set to 'no':

```
SET_HOSTNAME='no'
```

After rebooting your chosen hostname has to be active (you can also set it in that same session before rebooting with `hostname -F /etc/hostname` if you wish).

Answer (score 1):

$sudo vim /ect/hotname change what you want to use :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default is set in the `/etc/HOSTNAME` file.