# Should I change my server hostname?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, hostname

The hostname on my server is the default that is was when I purchased the dedicated server, but I am wondering if it is possible to change it, and if I should.

If I change the hostname, will it stop my server working and connecting to the network properly, or does changing the hostname have no effect at all?

My last question is what would I change the hostname to? My full domain name, such as example.com, or change it to something like hostname.example.com? Would I need to change some DNS records?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the hostname to a meaningful name will make the server administration easier by easily recognizing the server when you login. It should not affect the server functionality. No need to change the DNS records. You just need to update the hosts file. To change the hostname, look at [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/208647/unable-to-rename-linux-hostname/208664#208664).

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing that up, I just wanted to make sure it had no bad effects on my system. The solution you gave me worked nicely.